# Different results for N>1 goroutines (on N>1 Cpu:s). Why?

Tags: concurrency, go, channel

I have a test program that gives different results when executing more than one goroutine on more than one Cpu (Goroutines = Cpus). The "test" is about syncing goroutines using channels, and the program itself counts occurences of chars in strings. It produces consistent results on one Cpu / one goroutine.

See code example on playground (Note: Run on local machine to execute on multi core, and watch the resulting numbers vary): http://play.golang.org/p/PT5jeCKgBv .

**Code summary**: The program counts occurences of 4 different chars (A,T, G,C) in (DNA) strings.

**Problem**: Result (n occurences of chars) varies when executed on multiple Cpu's (goroutines). Why?

**Description**:

1. A goroutine spawns work (**SpawnWork**) as strings to **Workers**.  Sets up
   artificial string input data (hardcoded strings are  copied n times).
2. Goroutine **Workers** (Worker) are created equalling the numbers of Cpu's.
3. **Workers** checks each char in string and counts A,T's and sends the
   sum into a channel, and G,C counts to another channel.
4. **SpawnWork** closes workstring channel as to control Workers (which consumes strings using range, which quits when the input channel is closed by **SpawnWork**).
5. When **Workers** has consumed its ranges (of chars) it sends a quit signal on the quit channel (quit <- true). These "pulses" will occure  Cpu number of times ( Cpu count = goroutines count).
6. **Main** (select) loop will quit when it has received Cpu-count number of quit
   signals.
7. **Main** func prints a summary of occurences of Chars (A,T's, G,C's).

**Simplified code**:

***1.** "Worker" (goroutines) counting chars in lines:*

```
func Worker(inCh chan *[]byte, resA chan<- *int, resB chan<- *int, quit chan bool) {
    //for p_ch := range inCh {
    for {
        p_ch, ok := <-inCh // similar to range
        if ok {
            ch := *p_ch
            for i := 0; i < len(ch); i++ {
                if ch[i] == 'A' || ch[i] == 'T' {        // Count A:s and T:s
                    at++
                } else if ch[i] == 'G' || ch[i] == 'C' { // Count G:s and C:s
                    gc++
                }
            }
            resA <- &at  // Send line results on separate channels
            resB <- &gc  // Send line results on separate channels
        } else {
            quit <- true // Indicate that we're all done
            break
        }
    }
}
```

***2.** Spawn work (strings) to workers:*

```
func SpawnWork(inStr chan<- *[]byte, quit chan bool) {
    // Artificial input data
    StringData :=
        "NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN\n" +
        "NTGAGAAATATGCTTTCTACTTTTTTGTTTAATTTGAACTTGAAAACAAAACACACACAA\n" +
        "... etc\n" +
    // ...
    for scanner.Scan() {
        s := scanner.Bytes()
        if len(s) == 0 || s[0] == '>' {
            continue
        } else {
            i++
            inStr <- &s
        }
    }
    close(inStr) // Indicate (to Workers) that there's no more strings coming.
}
```

***3.** Main routine:*

```
func main() {
    // Count Cpus, and count down in final select clause
    CpuCnt := runtime.NumCPU() 
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(CpuCnt)
    // Make channels
    resChA := make(chan *int)
    resChB := make(chan *int)
    quit := make(chan bool)
    inStr := make(chan *[]byte)

    // Set up Workers ( n = Cpu )
    for i := 0; i < CpuCnt; i++ {
        go Worker(inStr, resChA, resChB, quit)
    }
    // Send lines to Workers
    go SpawnWork(inStr, quit)

    // Count the number of "A","T" & "G","C" per line 
    // (comes in here as ints per row, on separate channels (at and gt))
    for {
        select {
        case tmp_at := <-resChA:
            tmp_gc := <-resChB // Ch A and B go in pairs anyway
            A += *tmp_at       // sum of A's and T's
            B += *tmp_gc       // sum of G's and C's
        case <-quit:
            // Each goroutine sends "quit" signals when it's done. Since 
            // the number of goroutines equals the Cpu counter, we count 
            // down each time a goroutine tells us it's done (quit at 0):
            CpuCnt--
            if CpuCnt == 0 { // When all goroutines are done then we're done.
                goto out     
            }
        }
    }
out:
    // Print report to screen
}
```

Why does this code count consistently only when executed on a singel cpu/goroutine? That is, the channels doesn't seem to sync, or the main loop quits forcefully before all goroutines are done? Scratching head.

(Again: See/run the full code at the playground: http://play.golang.org/p/PT5jeCKgBv )

// Rolf Lampa

Comment: Have you tried running it with `go run -race`? http://golang.org/doc/articles/race_detector.html

Comment: I looked through the code and didn't see any problems so I tried `-race` myself. It found a few problems but one of them is that the `at` variable at the beginnning of `Worker` is exposed to `main` because you do `tmp_at := <-resChA`. Maybe if you pass the numbers themselves through the channels (instead of pointers to the numbers) then it won't be racy?

Comment: @MatrixFog: I actually had forgot about the -race option. Doh! However, removing the pointers does not do away with the races, that really puzzles me. I'll keep trying to narrowing it down.

Comment: See discussion with Nick Craig-Wood below about all the problems, both apparent and (potentially) hidden that was revealed. Many lessons learned in one..., well, go. :)

Comment: Tying the number of goroutines to be the same as the number of CPUs is a risky policy - it may sometimes lead to under-utilisation of CPUs, especially if I/O is involved. In your case, you might well be lucky though. The alternative policy is to use 'excess parallelism' - i.e. more goroutines than there are CPUs. Even when some of them get blocked (e.g. on channels) there are others that the CPU cores can carry on executing.

Comment: @Rick-777: Yes, there may be reason to utilize more goroutines as the channeling also takes some overhead. Also to regard is that in the "non playground" version there's disk access that limits the overall speed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working version which consistently produces the same results no matter how many cpus are used.

Here is what I did

- remove passing of `*int` - very racy to pass in a channel!
- remove passing of `*[]byte` - pointless as slices are reference types anyway
- copy the slice before putting it in the channel - the slice points to the same memory causing a race
- fix initialisation of `at` and `gc` in `Worker` - they were in the wrong place - this was the major cause of the difference in results
- use [sync.WaitGroup](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup) for synchronisation and channel close()

I used the [`-race` parameter of go build](http://golang.org/doc/articles/race_detector.html) to find and fix the data races.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "strings"
    "sync"
)

func Worker(inCh chan []byte, resA chan<- int, resB chan<- int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    fmt.Println("Worker started...")
    for ch := range inCh {
        at := 0
        gc := 0
        for i := 0; i < len(ch); i++ {
            if ch[i] == 'A' || ch[i] == 'T' {
                at++
            } else if ch[i] == 'G' || ch[i] == 'C' {
                gc++
            }
        }
        resA <- at
        resB <- gc
    }

}

func SpawnWork(inStr chan<- []byte) {
    fmt.Println("Spawning work:")
    // An artificial input source.
    StringData :=
        "NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN\n" +
            "NTGAGAAATATGCTTTCTACTTTTTTGTTTAATTTGAACTTGAAAACAAAACACACACAA\n" +
            "CTTCCCAATTGGATTAGACTATTAACATTTCAGAAAGGATGTAAGAAAGGACTAGAGAGA\n" +
            "TATACTTAATGTTTTTAGTTTTTTAAACTTTACAAACTTAATACTGTCATTCTGTTGTTC\n" +
            "AGTTAACATCCCTGAATCCTAAATTTCTTCAGATTCTAAAACAAAAAGTTCCAGATGATT\n" +
            "TTATATTACACTATTTACTTAATGGTACTTAAATCCTCATTNNNNNNNNCAGTACGGTTG\n" +
            "TTAAATANNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN\n" +
            "NNNNNNNCTTCAGAAATAAGTATACTGCAATCTGATTCCGGGAAATATTTAGGTTCATAA\n"
    // Expand data n times
    tmp := StringData
    for n := 0; n < 1000; n++ {
        StringData = StringData + tmp
    }
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(strings.NewReader(StringData))
    scanner.Split(bufio.ScanLines)

    var i int
    for scanner.Scan() {
        s := scanner.Bytes()
        if len(s) == 0 || s[0] == '>' {
            continue
        } else {
            i++
            s_copy := append([]byte(nil), s...)
            inStr <- s_copy
        }
    }
    close(inStr)
}

func main() {
    CpuCnt := runtime.NumCPU() // Count down in select clause
    CpuOut := CpuCnt           // Save for print report
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(CpuCnt)
    fmt.Printf("Processors: %d\n", CpuCnt)

    resChA := make(chan int)
    resChB := make(chan int)
    inStr := make(chan []byte)

    fmt.Println("Spawning workers:")
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < CpuCnt; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go Worker(inStr, resChA, resChB, &wg)
    }
    fmt.Println("Spawning work:")
    go func() {
        SpawnWork(inStr)
        wg.Wait()
        close(resChA)
        close(resChB)
    }()

    A := 0
    B := 0
    LineCnt := 0
    for tmp_at := range resChA {
        tmp_gc := <-resChB // Theese go together anyway
        A += tmp_at
        B += tmp_gc
        LineCnt++
    }

    if !(A+B > 0) {
        fmt.Println("No A/B was found!")
    } else {
        ABFraction := float32(B) / float32(A+B)
        fmt.Println("\n----------------------------")
        fmt.Printf("Cpu's  : %d\n", CpuOut)
        fmt.Printf("Lines  : %d\n", LineCnt)
        fmt.Printf("A+B    : %d\n", A+B)
        fmt.Printf("A      : %d\n", A)
        fmt.Printf("B      : %d\n", A)
        fmt.Printf("AB frac: %v\n", ABFraction*100)
        fmt.Println("----------------------------")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your elaborate answer! Unfortunately the pointers alone don't seem to be the problem (removing all ptrs doesn't do away with the races). The exact (and only) cause of the race problem was a conflict with the s (string), caused by scanner replacing it while reading in workers. That problem you also have solved in your code using a copy of s ( "s_copy := append([]byte(nil), s...)" ). Thank you very very much for pointing that one out! Also thank you for your alternative strategy with the wait-groups. Gold! :)

Comment: In addition to spotting the race problem above, I would like to point out why all the pointers in my example (they actually makes sense). I used this example algorithm from a (language) performance test for reading DNA sequences. Ptrs were optimizations which made a significant difference. It could be of interest to see how Go-lang did compared to C, C++, D, Pascal, Phyton etc. (super optimized (go) speed: https://gist.github.com/samuell/5591369) . Comparison: http://saml.rilspace.org/moar-languagez-gc-content-in-python-d-fpc-c-and-c (Go did very well!) :)

Comment: Hint: If you point out that the race problem was the scan string (which you copied), then I can endorse your answer as "The answer". And yes, the initialization of the variables in the worker got accindently moved when trying to replace the "for... range" loop (it originally was inside the loop). So ponting out those two fixes solves the entire problem, even if keeping the pointers and all the rest as is in the original code.

Comment: The `*[]byte` and the `*int` pointers can both cause races (and the race detector agrees) but since your channels aren't buffered they didn't this time! Try your example using buffered channels (give a second parameter to `make(chan XXX, 1000)`) and you'll see the races come into play I suspect.  You'll also see a performance rise.

Comment: Good and safe general strategies indeed, but regarding the actual code (and problem) my race detector went quiet and the results went stable when copying the string, that is, while keeping the pointers. But I also tried adding buffers (as you suggest), to the original code (except for the fixed copied string), and I get no detected races, BUT - the results starts to vary again! So what I get with pointers is *undetected* races. As a next step, I removed the pointers (as you suggested) and then the results went OK again. I'm truly amazed by your insights and advice. See The answer. Thumbs up.:)

Comment: @Nick_Craig-Wood: Notice though that the original code works perfectly well both with buffered channels and "as is" if: #1. sending copies of the string, and #2. removing pointers, all according to your advice. This is just to point out that the "channel signal" strategy for quitting the goroutines gracefully actually works, and wait.groups works too. But with your advice all the problems, including potential problems when buffering the channels, are done away with in all cases. This was a really enlightening lesson. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to be of service! Interesting the race detector didn't detect all the races - a good experiment. The channel strategy for quitting is fine - I think the WaitGroup is neater though - perhaps I shouldn't have changed that as it didn't directly illustrate the fix, but I can't resist trying to make code more beautiful!

Comment: You are excused for making the code so much more beautiful. :)

Comment: Perhaps you should contribute to the golang project by enhancing the -race detector? :) At least a warning (or "attention"?) for the combination channel Buffers && Pointers would seem to be a valuable contribution to the race detector. (unless there are any hidden caveeats with it).